# Java KeyFactory.generatePublic equivalent in C# for RSA Encryption

Tags: java, c#, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have this Java code to create a public key based on base64 byte array in Java:

```
return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(base64PublicKeyBytes));
```

That line is subsequently used to encrypt some data.

Assume that I have access to the base64 encoded public key string.
Would the equivalent C# code to generate the key be as simple as:

```
base64PublicKeyBytes =  Convert.FromBase64String(base64PublicKey);
```

and this can then be used with RSACryptoServiceProvider as follows:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
                    var rsaKeyInfo = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
                    rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = base64PublicKeyBytes;
```

Comment: No, it would not be that simple. .NET does not have support for that format of public key, also known as SubjectPublicKeyInfo format. There are a few ways to deal with this. One is to use the Bouncycastle C# library which does support this format. Another is to convert it to a format .NET supports, like the XML format of `RSA.ToXMLString()`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I figured it was not as straight forward.  Here is what I am trying:   #if WINDOWS
                    var existingPublicKeyData = rsa.ToXmlString(false);

                    // extract the original exponent and re-use
                    var exponent = ParseExponentFromPublicKeyInfo(existingPublicKeyData);
                    var keyInfo = CreateRSARequiredKeyFormatCreateRSARequiredKeyFormat(exponent, orgEncryptionKey);    

                    Console.WriteLine("Re-import key information. ");
                    rsa.FromXmlString(keyInfo);
#endif